# Why is /usr/share/gnome-shell/js missing?

Tags: linux, fedora, javascript, gnome3, gnome-shell

I'm trying to debug a gnome-shell extension, but I don't seem the have the folder /usr/share/gnome-shell/js. I'm on fedora 20 with gnome 3.12. I couldn't find it when I had gnome 3.10 either. Were the files moved? Is there a package that I'm missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The js files are now embedded inside `libgnome-shell.so`.

```
gresource list /usr/lib/gnome-shell/libgnome-shell.so
```

You can create a simple script to extract the resources:

```
#! /bin/sh

gs=/usr/lib/gnome-shell/libgnome-shell.so

cd $HOME/gnome-shell-js

mkdir -p ui/components ui/status misc perf extensionPrefs gdm

for r in `gresource list $gs`; do
  gresource extract $gs $r > ${r/#\/org\/gnome\/shell/.}
done
```

And then use:

```
GNOME_SHELL_JS=$HOME/gnome-shell-js gnome-shell --replace
```

To check the changes.

Be careful, when you exit the replacement shell, the previous one becomes unresponsive.

This was taken from [Gnome blog post](https://blogs.gnome.org/mclasen/2014/03/24/keeping-gnome-shell-approachable/).

Comment: On a 64-bit system, my path to gnome-shell was /usr/lib64/gnome-shell/libgnome-shell.so

Also, I needed to add portalHelper to the list of directories to add via mkdir.